# javascript loop over .onclick and query

Tags: javascript, django

So this results in the last element having the onclick function. Nothing else works. 
I tried to follow previous answers by wrapping i in () but that didn't seem to do anything...

```
function waitForLoad(id, callback){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(id)){
            clearInterval(timer);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}
// to skip the LocationSet and LocationName, because we want to reuse our old Location
ref = new Firebase("https://iplus1app.firebaseio.com/");
userLocs = ref.child("users/{{ user.username }}/locations");
// create the button function to redirect for each Location that exists
userLocs.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
    for  (i = 0; i < snapshot.numChildren(); i++) { 
        var locationKey = keys[i]
        //var locationKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val()[keys[i]])
        var nickName = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['name']
        locLat = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['position']['lat']
        locLng = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['position']['lng']
        locNick = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['name']   
        waitForLoad(nickName, function(){
                document.getElementById(nickName).onclick = (function(i) {
                    return function (i) {
                        tempRef = ref.child("users/{{ user.username }}/temp_location"); 
                        tempRef.set( {
                            position: {
                                lat: locLat, 
                                lng: locLng
                            },
                            name:  locNick            
                        })
                        location.href = "{% url 'tutorLocationActivities' %}";
                    }
                })(i);
        });         
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to show the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what `snapshot.val()` looks like, could you please post an example (`console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(),undefined,2))`)?

Some other code is generating html elements and you are waiting for that other code to have created the elements?

I'm not sure why you need the `waitForLoad`, if you have no jQuery (`document.ready`) you can add your script just before the `</body>` tag or use `defer` attribute (assuming the elements you want to add event listener to are static).

It looks like you have not set the closure correctly in the for loop, you probably meant to do something like this:

```
var i;//your for loop creates a global variable called i
for  (i = 0; i < snapshot.numChildren(); i++) { 
  waitForLoad(
    snapshot.val()[keys[i]]['name']
    ,(function(index){
      //create closure variables based on index
      var locationKey = keys[index]
      ,nickName = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['name']
      ,locLat = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['position']['lat']
      ,locLng = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['position']['lng']
      ,locNick = snapshot.val()[locationKey]['name'];
      return function(){
        document.getElementById(nickName).onclick = 
          function (event) {
            tempRef = ref.child("users/{{ user.username }}/temp_location"); 
            tempRef.set(
              {
                position: {
                  lat: locLat, 
                  lng: locLng
                },
                name:  locNick            
              }
            );
            location.href = "{% url 'tutorLocationActivities' %}";
          }
        ;
      }
    }(i))
  );
}
```